# Hiding div after ajax submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this small issue, regarding an ajax form that i'm submitting (with success).

I followed a tutorial (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/), and the form that it is submitting is just a standard contact form. However mine is sending a message through the form, and thus I want to display a message to the user, and then give the user the ability to remove the message on click.

1. Form sends message.
2. User receives feedback (ajax)
3. How can I remove this div after it has been shown?

HTML

```
<div class="module send-message" id="send-message">
                    <form name="send" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
                        <fieldset>

                        <label for="recipient" id="recipient_label">Your recipient(s):</label>
                        <input type="text" name="recipient" id="recipient" class="pure-input-1 input-tags"></input>                     
                        <label class="error" id="recipient_error" for="recipient">This field is required.</label>  

                        <label for="message">Your message:</label>
                        <textarea name="message" maxLength="120" rows="4" class="pure-input-1" id="message"></textarea>
                        <label class="error" for="message" id="message_error">This field is required.</label>  

                        <p id="counter" style="margin-bottom: 25px;"><span>0</span> characters of 120</p>

                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_btn" class="button btn-large btn-warning" value="Pipit"></input>
                        </fieldset>

                    </form>
                </div>
```

JS/Jquery:

```
var dataString = 'recipient='+ recipient + '&message=' + message + '&terms=' + terms;  
    //alert (dataString);return false;  
    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "process.php",  
      data: dataString,  
      success: function() {  
        $('#send-message').html("<div id='feedback'></div>");  
        $('#feedback').html("<h2>Your message has been sent!</h2>")  
        .append("<p>Click anywhere to hide this message.</p>")  
        .hide()  
        .fadeIn();  
      }  
    });  
    return false;     
  });  
});
```

:: UPDATE ::
Thanks to a number of people on this fantastic site, I got it to work!

However, there are two minor flaws:

1. I want the form to be refreshed (all data removed from it).
2. When the feedback message is shown for the first time, it goes away like it should. However when i re-submit the form, the feedback form will linger to the bottom.

Can any1 help here?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a click function to the div like so:

```
$('#feedback').html("<h2>Your message has been sent!</h2>")  
        .append("<p>Click anywhere to hide this message.</p>")  
        .hide()  
        .fadeIn()
        .click(function(){    
            // Hide the div and remove it
            $(this).fadeOut(function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        )};
```

Or if you'd just like to auto hide the message you could use the jQuery `delay()` function or simply `setTimeout`. Here's how you'd use the `delay()` function:

```
$('#feedback').html("<h2>Your message has been sent!</h2>")  
        .append("<p>Click anywhere to hide this message.</p>")  
        .hide()  
        .fadeIn()
        .delay(1000)
        .fadeOut();
```

Alternatively here's an example using a `setTimeout` funciton:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#feedback').hide();
}, 1000);
```

The `1000` here relates to the number of milliseconds to wait before executing the code.

```
1000 miliseconds = 1 second
```

---

**EDIT:**

Ok so to make sure you're not replacing the form you need to append the message instead like this:

```
$('#send-message').append("<div id='feedback'></div>");
```

You can also temporarily hide the form and then show it once you're user has dismissed the feedback message:

```
$('#send-message form').hide();

// Add show form to the click function
.click(function(){    
            // Hide the div and remove it
            $(this).fadeOut(function(){
                $(this).remove();
                $('#send-message form').show();
            });
        )};
```

---

**FURTHER EDIT:**

```
// Simple jQuery Plugin
$.fn.clearForm = function() {
    $this = this;

    // Find inputs
    $this.find('input[type=text], select').val('');
    $this.find('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked');
};

// Usage
$('#form').clearForm();
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dUQ9T/5/

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
However, how do I show the original div containing my contact form again?

Comment: Can you post your html for the form too?

Comment: The HTML has been added :)

Comment: I hate to bug you being so close to the final answer now! I opted to go with the solution where the feedback statement is posted below the form. However is there a way to make a 'clean slate/refresh' for the form?

Comment: You can create an easy form clear function for sure. See edit :)

Comment: Where would that code part go? I tried to put it into the document as a separate script, but didn't seem to do much, (also changed the ID to correct one?) Is it supposed to go into the javascript file containing the ajax? :)
Thanks so far though, u're a great help!

Comment: Ah apologies left a rogue "." in there...here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate it http://jsfiddle.net/dUQ9T/5/

Comment: It finally worked! However only for the text area field that I have. But maybe that has something to do with my input field, which is used by another script called selectize.js. 

Thank you though! I have marked as correct for you answer, and your ability to help has been amazing, thanks Steve!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for you:

Change this line of code:

```js
$('#send-message').html("<div id='feedback'></div>");
```

to:

```js
$('#send-message').html("<div id='feedback' onclick='hideMe()'></div>");
```

then add:

```js
var hideMe = function () {
    $("#feedback").hide();
}
```

if you just want to hide it.  If you want to remove it completely, then use .remove() instead of .hide();

```js
var hideMe = function () {
    $("#feedback").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this, on click first fades it out then removes it from the dom completely.

```
var dataString = 'recipient='+ recipient + '&message=' + message + '&terms=' + terms;  
    //alert (dataString);return false;  
    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "process.php",  
      data: dataString,  
      success: function() {  
        $('#send-message').html("<div id='feedback'></div>");  
        var $feedback = $('#feedback');
        $feedback.html("<h2>Your message has been sent!</h2>").append("<p>Click anywhere to hide this message.</p>");
        $feedback.on("click", function () {
               $(this).fadeOut(function () {
                     $(this).remove();
               });
            });              
        $feedback.fadeIn();  
      }  
    });  
    return false;     
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

$('#feedback').on('click',function() {
   $(this).hide();
});

Assign a click event to your feedback div that causes it to hide when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#send-message').html("<div id='feedback' onclick='$(this).hide();'></div>");
```

Comment: This works! However the original window (containing the form) does not reappear again?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to offer the end-user the possibility to hide the `#feedback` div wherever he clicks in the document, you could add an event handler to the document and hide the `#feedback` div whenever a click event occurs:

```
// jQuery
$(document).on('click', function(){
    $('#feedback').hide();

    // to show the form again
    $('#formID').show();
}); 

// no jQuery
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('feedback').style.display = none;

    // show the form again
    document.getElementById('formID').style.display = block;
});
```

If you want your user to close that div when he clicks inside the `#feedback` div, simply change the element that listens for that click event:

```
// jQuery
$('#feedback').on('click', function(){
    $(this).hide();

    // show the form
    $('#formID').show();
}); 

// no jQuery
document.getElementById('feedback').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.display = none;

    // if you want to show the form
    document.getElementById('formID').style.display = block;
});
```

**EDIT1**: I have updated my answer to show the form div as soon as the feedback div gets hidden. If your form div gets empty after you receive the feedback, you could cache the for m HTML at the beginning of your script, or copy that div in a variable and append it to the div when you re-display your form.

Comment: Nice solution! Easy and simple :)
How do I show the original div again? (containing the form)